# reverse base58 encoding - decoding?

Tags: javascript, base58

On this site [forknote creator](http://forknote.net/create/) in the second input box you enter a decimal value and it display the decoded prefix on the right.

Is it possible to reverse the js function so that you can enter text ie "BOB" and it displays the decimal value?

I think the "BOB" need to be converted to bytes? then to base 58 hex and convert the hex to dec?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every value encoded by baseXX function can be decoded. But this answer doesn't solve your problem. I looked at the code behind this input and it's way more complicated and has many cryptographic functions. I don't know if it's reversible.